# onClick function won't execute in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Original Source: https://gist.github.com/Schachte/a95efbf7be0c4524d1e9ac2d7e12161c

I have an onClick on a button. It was working with my previous modal and now, with a new modal, it doesn't fire. I'm particularly concerned with the line at the bottom:

```
<button className="remodal-confirm" onClick={event => this.onClick(event)}>Feed Me</button>
```

If I take this out of the div and put it at the top of the return, the button works..

## Update

I've narrowed down errors coming from things being nested inside this modal. It's a standard JS modal, not setup for react. Not sure how this could be a problem or a solution.

## Code:

```
class ModalWindow extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}


onClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    console.log("executed");
} 






render() {

    console.log(this.state.zipCode);

    if (this.props.zipCode){
        this.renderNeighbors(this.props.zipCode)
    }
    return ( 
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.renderNeighbors(this.props.zipCode)}
            </ul>
            
                <div className="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
                  <button data-remodal-action="close" className="remodal-close"></button>
                  <h3>FrugalEats Search Information</h3>

                  <hr/>

                  <span>
                  <i className="fa fa-info" aria-hidden="true"></i> The information below will query restaurants and menus items that you can afford in your area.
                  </span>
                  <hr/>
       
                    <span className="input input--kaede">
                        <input className="input__field input__field--kaede" type="text" id="input-35" placeholder="$5.00" onChange={ event => { this.setState( { priceLimit: event.target.value } ) } }/>
                        <label className="input__label input__label--kaede" htmlFor="input-35">
                            <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede">Price Limit</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span className="input input--kaede">
                        <input className="input__field input__field--kaede" type="text" id="input-36" placeholder="Goldwater Engineering Tempe, AZ" onChange={ event => { this.setState( { zipCode: event.target.value } ) } }/>
                        <label className="input__label input__label--kaede" htmlFor="input-36">
                            <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede">Location</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
                    <span className="input input--kaede">
                        <input className="input__field input__field--kaede" type="text" id="input-37" placeholder="2.5" onChange={ event => { this.setState( { radiusMax: event.target.value } ) } }/>
                        <label className="input__label input__label--kaede" htmlFor="input-37">
                            <span className="input__label-content input__label-content--kaede">Radius (Miles)</span>
                        </label>
                    </span>
    

                  <br/>
                  <button data-remodal-action="cancel" className="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
                  <button className="remodal-confirm" onClick={event => this.onClick(event)}>Feed Me</button>
                </div>
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you have the developmental presets with Babel so it supports class properties?

Answer (score 0):

The fat arrow syntax for class methods is not supported in ES6 - try changing your method definition to:

```
onClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  console.log("executed");
}
```

also the following lines:

```
if (this.props.zipCode){
  this.renderNeighbors(this.props.zipCode)
}
```

are outside of the render function's *return* statement; you should consider changing them to something like:

```
return ( 
  { this.props.zipCode ? this.renderNeighbors(this.props.zipCode) : null }

   <div>
     <button 
       className="remodal-confirm" 
       onClick={event => this.onClick(event)}>Feed Me
     </button>

     // rest of code...
   </div>
);
```

and finally, if you thinks it's due to the layout of the jsx (you say it worked when 'outside the div') I'd try 'binary chopping' - selectively remove chunks of jsx until you identify the offending section.